# setting height on tableviewcell from uiimageview size

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView populated with custom cells.
I have created the type StripTableViewCell with a UIImageVIew.

```
@interface StripTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *strip;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *strip;

@end
```

The StripTableViewCell is initialized with a new UIImageView:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
        strip = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:strip];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The ContentMode of the UIImageView is set to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; to make the image fit full width of the cell.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    strip.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGRect frame;
    frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, contentRect.size.width, contentRect.size.height);

    strip.frame = frame;
}
```

The cell is populated like this:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StripCell";

    StripTableViewCell *cell = (StripTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[StripTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    Strip *strip = [self.stripsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:strip.data];
    cell.strip.image = [img autorelease];

    return cell;
}
```

The images can be of different height, so I'll have to fit the height of the cell to the imageview's height.
Now, my problem is that i want the cell height to fit the height of the imageview.
I gave it a shot by finding the current cell and return the height of the imageview from that cell, but it renders completely wrong sizes.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    StripTableViewCell *cell = (StripTableViewCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *picture = cell.strip;

    return picture.bounds.size.height; 
}
```

My app then only renders the first image and the cell i the wrong size.
So i guess my approach is somewhat wrong here. Could you guys help me in the right direction?

PS: Dont mind memory management in the above exampls, these are cut out from the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that could be going wrong here, and you don't include any code that shows how your create and initialize the UIImageView in your UITableViewCell subclass.   Make sure you're setting the frame size of the "IBOutlet UIImageView *strip" correctly.  Remember that the UIImageView will present the image according to the UIImageView's frame and contentMode, and the size of the image.    You say that you set the contentMode of the cell, but do you set the contentMode of the UIImageView?    If you want the image to be displayed full size within your UIImageView then you will need to modify the frame size of the UIImageView to match the bounds of the UIImage you set into it.

Edit: the problem that your self-answer solves is that you're basing the row height off of the height of the *image*, not the height of the *imageview*.   Setting an image into an imageview does not change the size of the imageview's frame!    Once you've returned the correct height of the row, this "flows" to the height of the contentView, and that flows to the height of the UIImageView, according to your code.

You could solve the double-create just by caching the UIImage in a dictionary and re-using it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I have added the requested code. Of course i meant the contentMode of the UIImageView, my mistake.

Comment: I'm still suspicious about the frame of the UIImageView.  If you NSLog the frame of the UIImageView in cellForRowAtIndexPath, do you get sane values?

Comment: That doesn't look like a sane value for a frame to me.   Make sure you print out frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height, as "%f".

Comment: @Bogatyr Thanks I'll play around with it. Have you seen my suggestion for a solution below? I thisnk the problem is that when layoutSubviews is called the ImageView on the cell hasen't been populated yet and because of that theImageView doesent have the size, it will take when i assign a image to it and it is fitted. Thats why i this i have to resize it AFTER the image has been appended.

Comment: Yes check my edit.   You need to base everything off the size of the image, and fit the imageview's frame to the image size.   Cache the UIImage object so you only need to create it once.

Comment: Thats how I'm gonna do it. Instead of having the image data in my dictionary, I'll go for your idea and have the created UIImage instead. Thank for the clearing up, Bogatyr.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found a way to do it by implementeing heightForRowAtIndexPath. But it seems kind of ugly, but here it is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    Strip *strip = [self.stripsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:strip.data] autorelease];
    CGImageRef image = img.CGImage;
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
    float factor = self.view.bounds.size.width/(float)width;
    return height*factor;   
}
```

It init's a nes UIImage with the same data i use to populate the UIImageView in the cell. From the original size and the width of the UITableView i calculate a factor, which I use to multiply the height accordingly. This works but it's kind of ugly and i dont think this solution performs very well.

Any better ideas?